# Enable AWS Session Support

Tags: php, session, amazon-web-services, web-hosting

Honestly I'm not entirely sure what the above means. I got on with the customer support that my site template provides and they didn't seem to know what they were asking for either. I have searched the web high and low for more information to enabling this option on AWS with no luck (I'm sure some wise guy will provide a link the answers the question). Anyways below is a screenshot of where I am seeing this asked for, it is on initial site configuration. Thanks in advance!!!

[image: See the Session Support label]

Comment: So is this is some kind of package that you want to install on AWS?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/session.installation.php  Your PHP was compiled WITHOUT sessions, and there's nothing you can do to enable it short of recompiling/reinstalling PHP

Comment: Yes, I have a [link](http://flynax.com) site that I want to push up to AWS, I can get in and edit whatever I need since I have the source code but I don't really want to enable php session handling if that will destroy aws scaling which from what I have read it will, since php session handling uses a single file so once you are using multiple servers if that file hasn't been passed on to the "slave" servers then sessioning will stop working. Feel free to correct me here. Thanks again for the comments, hope we can get this figured out.

Comment: Dows AWS really have a reputation for not scaling well when sessions are involved! I guess some of the incredibly high volume concurrent user sites that use sessions (such as my own) must have found some kind of workround.... perhaps by not using the filesystem for sessions.... elasticache is extremely useful as an alternative

Comment: I'll look into using the elasticcache and report back.

Comment: Storing sessions on the file system is not the only option for session management in PHP. ElastiCache or any other memcache system is definitely an option. The AWS SDK for PHP provides a [DynamoDB Session Handler](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-dynamodb-session-handler.html) that might work as well.